# Continue to get indexing out of range error

Tags: python, indexing

Here is my code:
*Student_IDs is a dictionary

```
def avg_GPAwork(work_choice):

    work = []
    work = list((Student_IDs.values()))
    print(work)

    for hours in range(len(work)):
        student_hours = work([hours][6])
        print(student_hours)
```

Here is what work is:

```
[
    ['Childs, Julia', '9939456', '12/12/1993', 'Computer Science', '3.89', '8'],
    ['Gaga, Lady', '7733469', '10/10/1980', 'Computer Science', '1.20', '40'],
    ['Joe, Billy', '80978632', '01/10/1992', 'Undeclared', '2.4', '25'],
    ['Armstrong, Lance', '0034728', '07/21/1993', 'Computer Science', '3.47', '10'],
    ['Cronkite, Walter', '4357349', '10/02/1992', 'Math', '3.21', '0'],
    ['Williams, Serena', '8453392', '02/14/1994', 'Math', '3.09', '5'],
    ['Harmond, Josh', '30145692', '12/03/1994', 'Biology', '3.9', '0'],
    ['Pawlakos, Eric', '1234567', '05/23/1993', 'Statistics', '3.8', '8']
]
```

I continue to get an indexing out of range error. What am I doing wrong/how can i fix it?

Comment: Why do you have `work = []` before you immediately overwrite it? You don't have to declare the types of variables or anything like that.

Comment: You could make your future questions easier to read by including formatted code sections. There should be a tab at the top of the help popup when writing a question or answer that will help you out there.

Comment: Do not post a vague paraphrase of an error, copy and paste the actual error (with traceback). The error will usually include all the information that an experienced developer can use to immediately find your problem, even if you can't. Without that information, people will have to manually plod through your code to figure out what might be wrong, or guess at it.

Comment: You're not using `work_choice`. Is that going to go into your code at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
work([hours][6])
```

I don't know what you think that does, but it doesn't do what you're thinking. You probably wanted the following:

```
work[hours][5]
```

The first problem is that your parentheses cause the expression to be parsed as "Call the object `work` as if it were a function. The argument should be determined by creating a 1-element list `[hours]`, then getting the element at position 6".

The second problem is that indexing starts from 0, so if you want the 6th element, that's at index 5.

Note: range-len iteration is almost never a good idea. If you want to iterate over the elements of a list, do so directly:

```
for item in work:
    student_hours = item[5]
    print(student_hours)
```

or better yet, scrap the first half of the function and iterate over `Student_IDs.values()` directly:

```
for item in Student_IDs.values():
    student_hours = item[5]
    print(student_hours)
```

Comment: @aIKid: The IndexError hits first.

Comment: Mm.. I don't think so.

Comment: @aIKid: Try it: `1([1][1])`

Comment: Great explanation. But even the `for item in work:` is overkill; just scrap the first half of the function and start with `for item in Student_IDs.values():`.

Comment: @aIKid: The `IndexError` comes from the `[1][1]`. You're trying to get the second element of `[1]`, which doesn't have a second element. The `1(…)` (or `work(…)` in the OP's code) is a red herring which is leading you astray.

Comment: @aIKid: It's fun how novices can write code that confuses experienced developers. Python has pretty regular idioms, and you'd never write code remotely like that yourself, and therefore we have no good intuitions about what it does and have to work it out in our heads.